# Avengers vs X-Men ending: isn’t it all The Avengers fault?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men, avengers, avengers-vs-x-men

If in the very beginning of AvX events The Avengers wouldn’t interfere and attack the X-Men and end up splitting the Phoenix Force apart:

- Scott, Emma, and the Phoenix 5 would’ve never existed
- the Phoenix would’ve gone straight to Hope like it was supposed to
- Scott would’ve never destroyed the world, killed Xavier and so on

Does that mean that all those bad outcomes are actually the fault of Avengers' actions?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's a bit harsh blaming the Avengers for the situation. All they knew is that a potentially world destroying entity was heading straight to Earth. Even though most of them weren't at all involved in the Dark Phoenix saga, they will know all about it, and know the possibly disastrous consequences of it's arrival.

Yes, if they hadn't acted in that way then those things that you stated wouldn't have happened, but as far as they knew, if they didn't do anything then the Earth and far more may well be destroyed. They felt it to be far better to destroy the Phoenix force, than to gamble upon it ending well.

Also you say that the Phoenix would have gone straight to Hope. Remember that she did alot of training before she took on the Phoenix force, who knows if she would have been able to avoid being overtaken by the Phoenix force in much the same way that Jean Grey was without that training. If the Avengers had done nothing and let it all happen, then far worse things may have taken place.

Comment: This gives motivations for why they did what they did. But intentions aren't really relevant to "was outcome X due to actions of Y?"